# Can a Simple Group possess this property?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

If a simple group G is of order 168 then can I find subgroup of order 7 of G ? If so, then what is the number of subgroups of G of order 7 ?

Comment: Do you know Sylow's Theorem?

Comment: Yes, the answer is 8.Thank u I've got the answer.

Comment: I think the question has mentioned simple to avoid the proper normal subgroup case.

Answer (score 2):

Since $168=7\cdot 24$, Sylow's Theorem says that:

- $n_7 \mid 24$
- $n_7 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$

Since the group is simple, we have

- $n_7 > 1$

Therefore, $n_7=8$ because $8$ is the only non-trivial divisor of $24$ that is congruent to $1 \bmod 7$.

Comment: Thank u for your responses. I m clear now.

Comment: low hanging fruit strikes again!

Comment: @DavidWheeler, fair enough, but many questions  are left unanswered even though they are answered in the comments.

Comment: And you are justly rewarded for the service you provide :)